# Gulp task: write content of a file to the disk if an error occurs

Tags: javascript, error-handling, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have a Gulp task to concatenate JavaScript source files into a single one and minify it:

```
    gulp.task('build', function() {
        var destinationFile = 'final.js';
        var dest = 'dest/';

        return gulp.src('**/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(destinationFile))      // Concat files
            .pipe(uglify({}))                   // Minify
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));             // Save final file to dest
    });
```

If one of the JavaScript file has a syntactic error, the `uglify` plugin raise an error. I can check the error, listening to it:

```
    var gutil = require('gulp-util');

    gulp.task('build', function() {
        var destinationFile = 'final.js';
        var dest = 'dest/';

        return gulp.src('**/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(destinationFile))
            .pipe(uglify({}))   
            .on('error', gutil.log)           // Log errors
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
    });
```

The error, for example could be:

```
...
JS_Parse_Error {
     message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»',
     filename: 'final.js',
     line: 2204,
     col: 25,
     pos: 89101,
     stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eva...
```

Unfortunately I am not able to check the file `final.js` at line 2204 to see the error ad fix it in the original file. I am not able to do that because the file has not been written to the file system yet.

Sure I can write the file to the disk **before** calling `uglify` and inspect it later:

```
    var gutil = require('gulp-util');

    gulp.task('build', function() {
        var destinationFile = 'final.js';
        var dest = 'dest/';

        return gulp.src('**/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(destinationFile))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))         // Save file to disk before uglify it
            .pipe(uglify({}))   
            .on('error', gutil.log)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest)); 
    });
```

But in this way I write the same file 2 times and I don't like it (for example, is not very good for performance).

### My question is:

**Is it possible to write the file to disk only in an error occurs on uglify?**

Something like:

```
    var gutil = require('gulp-util');

    gulp.task('build', function() {
        var destinationFile = 'final.js';
        var dest = 'dest/';

        return gulp.src('**/*.js')
            .pipe(concat(destinationFile))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
            .pipe(uglify({}))   
            .on('error', function(err) {
               // ... save content of "dest" file somewhere...
            })
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest)); 
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's possible, but it's the completely wrong approach. You still won't know which file the error is in. Instead either switch the `concat()` and `uglify()` or put a linter at the beginning of your stream.

Comment: Thank you Sven for your comment. I don't like the idea to switch `concat` with `uglify` because I do not end up with the same file at the end. Adding a linter is, for sure, a better approach. 

I am just curious to know why are you saying that "it's the completely wrong approach". Is my request not Gulp complaint? Thank you.